# Rectangular drop shadow applied to Circle before drag starts

Tags: swiftui, draggable

I have this view.

```swift
var example: some View {
    Circle()
        .fill(Color.red)
        .frame(width: 50)
        .draggable(Image(systemName: "circle")) {
            Circle()
                .fill(Color.green)
                .frame(width: 100)
                .contentShape(.dragPreview, Circle())
        }  
}
```

I don't want the lift effect to be applied to my circle with a rectangular drop shadow. How can I prevent this? On the drag preview I can use the contentShape view modifier, but it doesn't work on the original view.

Before press:

[image: initial state]

On press before dragging:

[image: after press before dragging]

On drag:

[image: dragging]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On the drag preview I can use the `contentShape` view modifier, but it doesn't work on the original view.

It does. Perhaps you put `contentShape` after `draggable` when you tried? You should put `contentShape` before `draggable`.

```
Circle()
    .fill(Color.red)
    .frame(width: 50)
    .contentShape(.dragPreview, Circle())
    .draggable(Image(systemName: "circle")) {
        Circle()
            .fill(Color.green)
            .frame(width: 100)
            .contentShape(.dragPreview, Circle())
    }
```

Comment: Nice one. I didn't know there was a version of the ```.contentShape``` modifier that takes ```ContentShapeKinds``` as parameter.

Comment: That's it! Thank you! I thought I tried out that already, but apparently not.